# How to remove buildup limescale from glass shower screen?

Tags: cleaning, bathroom

I've noticed someone posted similar question to my problem and follow the advices offered on that thread. but I still find no solutions to remove the stubborn limescale from my shower screen. I've tried all the cleaning chemicals from the supermarket even used a fine sandpaper to scrub it, but still no joy.

Is it possible to remove it with industrial glass polisher like the optometrist does on glasses? Or is there professional limescale removal guys that I could call for this type of issues?

[image: state of the shower screen]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: If you have used fine sandpaper it's possible you have damaged the glass permanently.

Comment: Shower doors are made of tempered glass. After being scratched, e.g., by sandpaper, tempered glass tends to suddenly shatter into little cubes. https://www.quora.com/Why-can-a-small-chip-or-crack-in-tempered-glass-lead-to-it-shattering The good news is that, since it's likely damaged now, anyway, you have another reason to replace it in addition to the lime buildup.

Comment: @DrMoishe, I'd say _most_ shower doors are made of acrylic or similar type or plastic.

Comment: In my experience, most are tempered glass, both at homes and hotels. Long ago, I'd purchased an inexpensive plastic door, which quickly became scratched and clouded.

Answer (score 1):

White vinegar and baking soda mix - you can use a fold or two of toilet paper soaked in that mixture to keep it in place where it needs to defy gravity such as the underside of taps or on vertical shower screens. Make sure to literally soak the paper.

Comment: It is useless to mix vinegar and baking soda. There are a million places on the internet that tell you to use vinegar and baking soda as a cleaning solution. When you mix these ingredients, you get a satisfying reaction, but that's all you get; the ingredients react with each other, but not with anything else. Vinegar alone is useful for removing a high pH build-up(and it might be useful on your limescale)and baking soda alone is useful for removing a low pH build-up. If you're not sure, try one and then the other. But if you mix them, they neutralize each other and are of no use for anything.

Answer (score 0):

Once I cleaned a glass shower door with Clorox blue toilet cleaner. Leave it on for a minute and scrub it off with a scrubby sponge. Do not put it on granite. It will temporarily work, but it always comes back every couple weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Vinegar or vinegar concentrate helps.
Soak vigorously, wash off, dry.

That should absolutely do the trick.
If it is not completely gone, do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Lemon juice and water. I mix about a teaspoon of lemon juice with 1 cup of water in a spray bottle. Spray it on whatever you're cleaning, let it sit for about a minute. Using a good cleaning sponge, the buildup should come right off. I've also used this on stainless steel pots and pans to bring the shine back.

Answer (score 0):

Lime away is what I'd start with. Forget any baking soda mixture. They don't work for this level of scale. In the future, avoid this by using a squeegee after each shower. Prevention is easier than cleaning the buildup. Good Luck